# How to download a project from bitbucket to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to download a project from Bitbucket to android studio

I have the link to clone

- Clicked VCS
- Enable Version Control Integration

I don't see the bitbucket option: How to add the option

[image]

Comment: Just use Git. That should work.

Comment: bit bucket use mercurial or git version control so you have to select mercurial or git :)

Comment: Download [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) and install it. Then clone using SourceTree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

go this steps and you can clone repo from bitbucket into studio.

Answer (score 0):

File -> New -> Project from Version Control -> Git -> Enter url -> Clone